# Remove issue reference in GitHub

Tags: git, github

I was trying to refer some issue from public library within my github project issue. What I did is I was commenting on one of the issues listed in my project and I gave the reference to the actual issue listed out in public library.

example : https://github.com/public-library/issues/42

And when I click that link it says : @amitpchigadani amitpchigadani referenced this issue in `MyOrganisation/projectName` an hour ago.

But I want to remove that reference from the public library. Is it possible to do it now?

Note : I removed the reference later and checked, but that comment/alert still exist in public library issue.

Comment: I guess you need to remove the link to the issue

Comment: @Vampire I removed that reference and checked. Still it appears there.

Comment: Well, then I guess you cannot remove the reference because you **did** reference the issue. Maybe if you contact support they can tell you or do it for you. They are quite responsive and fast.

Comment: @Vampire Thank you, they helped me out.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

After contacting GitHub support, they told me that the issue reference will only be seen by the people who have access to that private project. 
Any other members will not see the comment or message `@amitpchigadani amitpchigadani referenced this issue in MyOrganisation/projectName`. I was somewhere worried about the privacy concerns, but this seems to be fine.

**Note** : Issue once referenced, message/comment cannot be removed there after.

Comment: As someone who frequently references the wrong issue, this is annoying.  Thanks for looking into it though.

Comment: this stinks   > Note : Issue once referenced, message/comment cannot be removed there after.

Comment: There is an issue for this on the [unofficial github issues list](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/1081)